# Show Button in LinearLayout always on Bottom of the screen while Scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a LinearLayout with a few Elements which is in a ScrollView.
Now i want to have a Button on Bottom of the Screen (not on Bottom of the ScrollView), which is always shown in front, also while Scrolling the rest of the content of this Layout. How can i achieve this?

This is my ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#e2e2e2">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/bgnLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/trElement"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/stopslayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            android:divider="@drawable/divider">

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And thats the part in the Code where I add my current Button (which is always shown on bottom of the ScrollView):

```
Button mpbtn = ButtonFactory.makeButton(m, R.string.openMap, R.color.AndroidBlue);
LinearLayout bgnLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bgnLayout);
bgnLayout.addView(mpbtn);
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why don't you just add the button at the bottom of the xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can add button to xml like this it's possible and you can make the button visible and invisible when you wish inside your activity class.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
          >
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#e2e2e2">
    /////



    </ScrollView>

    <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: it's not a shout my capslock was on.it's just a mere reminder..thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Another question to this: Now i have my button always in front, but when i scroll down in the ScrollView, the button lays over the last element of the list. How can i end the ScrollView before the Button begins?

Comment: for this you can go with different ways like include android:layout_above="button id" in the scrollview or set a specific height for the button and set android:layout_marginBottom="heightofbutton" inside scrollview.